# Cannot Add PFRelation values to a specific objet

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am creating an app where the user can create a group, and then add some information within that group. To do this, a `PFRObject` is created in the parse database and a `PFRelation` is also created for that object containing all the group info. I am having trouble adding the relation info into the object I want. Instead of the app adding the info to the already existing object, it creates a new object and relation, and adds the info into there. How can I add the data to the already existing object? Would appreciate any suggestions.

```
@IBAction func CreateNewGroupAction(sender: AnyObject) {
    var groupinfo = PFObject(className: "GroupInfo")
    groupinfo["User"] = PFUser.currentUser()?.username
    groupinfo["Interest"] = "Cars"
    groupinfo.save()

    let relationinfo = PFObject(className: "BeaterGroups")
    relationinfo["GroupName"] = "CarGuys"
    let relation = relationinfo.relationForKey("GroupInfo")
    relation.addObject(groupinfo)

    relationinfo.save()

}




 var dataparse: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

func loaddata (){


    var findgroups: PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "BeaterGroups")
    findgroups.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if error == nil && objects != nil {

            if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {

                for object in objects {

                    self.dataparse.addObject(object)

                }

            }

        }

  self.tableView.reloadData()
    }


}



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    loaddata()



}


override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.dataparse.count
}





override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {



    let cell: UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellidentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
    let cellDataParse: PFObject = self.dataparse.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! PFObject
    cell.textLabel?.text = cellDataParse.objectForKey("GroupName")! as? String
 return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you post more code so that we know where the already existing objects are, please...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this behaviour is expected using your current code. `let relationinfo = PFObject(className: "BeaterGroups")` is creating a new object, thus will add a new row.

What you need to do is to add the relation to an existing `BeaterGroups` object. This you can get by using a query, e.g.